# Referencing object variables in PHP is throwing a syntax error

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to clean up the code in one of my classes, but it's throwing up a bit of a problem.

What I want to do is put all the SQL queries from my class methods into properties that the methods can reference as needed. This is working fine when the SQL query does not depend on any variables, but when I try and incorporate variables into the query, it throws an error.

Probably easier to show the code to explain.

```
class Assignment {

  //Properties

  public $courseID;
  public $userID;
  public $date;

  //SQL query as property

  private $releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";

  //Method

  public function releaseAssignment(){
      global $db;
      $query = $db -> query($this -> releaseAssignmentSQL);
  }


}
```

Then the method is called using the following:

```
$assignment = new Assignment();

$assignment -> courseID = $db -> escape_value($_POST['courseID']);
$assignment -> userID = $db -> escape_value($_POST['userID']);
$assignment -> date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo $assignment -> releaseAssignment();
```

The problem I have is that when I first load the page (which includes other references to this class) it's crashing with the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in ... class.assignment.php on line 19
```

Where line 19 refers to the declaration of the `$releaseAssignment` property above

Can anyone explain why this is happening? It looks as though it's not possible to declare a new string property which references other properties, but I can't believe that to be true - or is it?

Comment: Get rid of this global variable! This is no good to your code. Global variables are one of these resources a language offers you but expecting you never to use it. Similar to the infamous "goto".

Comment: Yes I thought the global variable felt a bit wrong, but wasn't sure how else to access the database object from within a method (other than passing it in as an argument, which I doubt is a good option either!). Any advice?

Comment: Sure, @Chris! Encapsulate your database connection in a class and create a public method like getConnection or something like it, returning a valid connection created when you create a new instance of the class. This will allow you to avoid the global variable and yet access your connection wherever you want. Besides, all your database logic concerning errors, exception handling and other things could be placed inside this object. This makes all these things easier to find. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
private $releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";
```

The `$this` variable refers to the current instance. Because you're still *declaring* properties, there is no instance to reference (hence, no `$this`). Properties can be assigned different values during a class' lifetime, so an expression like this can't possibly work.

Either hard-code the values (which probably isn't what you want), or define a constructor and initialize the private property there:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";
}
```

Add to that that, AFAIK, the properties `$date`, `$courseID` and `$userID` don't have a value (`null`), this probably won't work either. What you really want to do is initialize these properties (either in the constructor or using setters), and *then* initialize the string:

```
public function __construct($date, $course, $user)
{
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->userID = $user;
    $this->courseID = $course;
    $this->releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";
}
```

Still, because properties can change during an instance's lifetime, concatenating their value is probably not something you'd want to do. What I'd do here is define a constant with placeholders, and a method that returns a string with the values of the properties filled in:

```
const REASSIGNMENT_QUERY = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = 1, dateReleased = '%s' WHERE courseID = %d AND userID = %d";

public function getQuery()
{
    return sprintf(
        self::REASSIGNMENT_QUERY,
        $this->date,
        $this->courseID,
        $this->userID
    );
}
```

That already looks a lot nicer. But when using variables in queries, it really pays of to learn how to use prepared statements...

On a side-note: using classes with `global` is the worst thing you can do if you want to write OO code. Objects should be stand-alone, and never rely on global state to do their job

---

#### Explaining why there's no `$this` when declaring properties

Well, put simply, when you declare a class, you're just describing what instances (the actual objects) will look like. The properties describe what data the instances will hold, and the methods describe what kind of work/actions the instances can preform.
When a class needs to access the data it contains, or call on one of its own methods (private/protected methods), you have to tell PHP where to look for that data. Because you're inside the class, you tell PHP to look at the current object: `$this`.

Read property access statements (`$this->date`) like so: *"From 'this' instance, get me the value of 'date'"*, or *"Inside 'this', look for 'date', and give me its value"*.

Like I said `$this` refers to the object, the instance of the class. The layout and functionality of that object is defined by the class, but the actual data is owned by the instance, not the class.
A class declaration, therefore, is not linked to an instance. Why? Because a single class can be instantiated an infinite amount of times. There's no way for PHP to know which `$this` you mean when you're declaring properties.

Put simply, this is a class, and here's where you can use `$this`:

```
class Foo
{
    private $declaration = 'This is part of the description, not an instance, no this';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //__construct is called when a new instance is created,
        //$this references our new instance
        //what happens here only affects this one instance
        $this->declaration = 'Not applicable anymore';
    }
}//end of declaration
```

So you can only use `$this` in methods, because methods will only kick into action when an instance exists. outside of methods `$this` doesn't work. Ever.

Extra info

What if you want a class declaration to set data that *will* affect all instances? Well, if that data is immutable (ie a string), you declare a constant:

```
class Foo
{
    const THIS_CANNOT_CHANGE = 123;

    public $instanceProperty = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->instanceProperty = self::THIS_CANNOT_CHANGE;
    }
}
```

PHP also has the `static` keyword, but seeing as you're still learning, I'm not going into that, because `static` tends to be abused, especially by people who are still coming to terms with the concepts of OOP. Bottom line is, if you write classes in PHP, and use `static`, take a step back. 9/10 times, it means you made a mistake, or are about to make one.

Comment: @Anant: Done, added a more verbose explanation

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed explanation, much appreciated. Interesting you mentioned the static keyword. I am aware of it and used it for a lot of the methods in this class - and I've just finished going through and changing them all to instance based methods after realising that they weren't appropriate at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference $this outside a method or function in a php class

```
 private $releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";
```

Try build your sql query with a method inside your class:

```
public function makeQuery () {

 $this->releaseAssignmentSQL = "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this -> date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this -> courseID."' AND userID = '".$this -> userID."'";

}
```

and then call it in your __construct function:

```
function __construct() {
     $this->makeQuery();
}
```

or you may do this somewhere else, before getting your query.

Comment: Omitting the visibility modifier is bad practice when declaring methods, and your constructor doesn't take into account the fact that the properties concatenated into the string aren't initialized ;)

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `$this` always points to the currently instantiated object (object context).
 You can access `$this` after an object is instantiated. 
Change your code as shown below:

```
class Assignment {

  public $courseID;
  public $userID;
  public $date;
  private $releaseAssignmentSQL;

  public function __construct()
  {
      // setting other properties
      // ....
      $this->releaseAssignmentSQL = ($this->date && $this->courseID && $this->userID)? "UPDATE StudentCourses SET released = '1', dateReleased = '" . $this->date . "' WHERE courseID = '".$this->courseID."' AND userID = '".$this->userID."'" : "";
  }

  //Method

  public function releaseAssignment(){
      global $db;
      $query = $db->query($this->releaseAssignmentSQL);
  }


}
```